# Algorithms for training a two motor powered rc car without steering servo

Tags: machine-learning, python, autonomous-vehicles

Previously, I have build a donkey car where the steering of the two front wheels was done using a motor servo. This project was a success and the car was able to drive autonomously after training was done.

source [Donkey Car 2](https://www.donkeycar.com/)

Now:
I have this  [Rc Car kit](https://images.app.goo.gl/ooXYvWmwYiNLqpwj6) that has two motors on the back, powering two wheels and a trolley wheel in front.
The steering is supposed to be done by playing around with the two back motors.

My question is:
Is there any method modify the donkey car code, so I can train the model?

Considering that Donkey Car uses the angle of the servo to train the model, and now I just have the information of the two back wheels and no servo steering the vehicle

Not sure if there approach that is specific to this concept.